# MPAndroidChart. Can't force labels to have an equal spacing

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroidChart library and can't make labels to have an equal spacing.

[image]

When setAvoidFirstLastClipping(false) I get this:

[image]

As you can see only label 1 has shifted, others two didn't move a bit. 
I also played with getXAxis().setSpaceBetweenLabels(10); The best outcome was:

[image]

Comment: solved or not ?